# How do I insert the value of a variable within an HTML attribute using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert a value that I'm getting from the url inside the HTML attribute, as follows:

I did this function

```
function urlId(qs) {
document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("data-channel-external-id", "qs.channelid"); 
}
urlId(qs);
```

I want to insert the value of this variable `qs.channelid` (`qs.channelid` is the variable of a function that I did to get a value from the ex url:www.mysite.com/pagina.php?id=VALOR that I want Get and set within the HTML attribute.
  So I made this code above and I put the following in my `data-channel-external-id="urlId(qs)"` attribute but it is not working ...

Comment: qs is a variable so you shouldn't be enclosing it in double inverted commas `document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("data-channel-external-id", qs.channelid)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If qs is a function, you must call the function before you can access its properties

```js
function qs() {
  // Do something in your function and set channelid on this (the function itself)
  this.channelid = "test";
  return this;
}

function urlId(qs) {
  var qsResult = qs();
  // Call the function, after that, you can access its properties: qs().channelid
  document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("data-channel-external-id", qsResult.channelid);
  document.getElementById('channelid').textContent = "Attribute data-channel-external-id=\"" + qsResult.channelid + "\" is set on the button";
}
urlId(qs);
```

```html
<button id="example" value="example">example</button>
<label id="channelid"></label>
```

In regards to your comment, you can set the channelid at any point in your code:

```js
function qs(url) {
  // Do something in your function and set channelid on this (the function itself)
  this.channelid = url;
  return this;
}

// pass the url as a parameter
var qsResult = qs("the-url-you-want");
console.log("When using the parameter: qsResult.channelid === \"" + qsResult.channelid + "\"");

// or don't use a parameter and set the url later on
var qsResultWithoutParameter = qs();
console.log("When not using the parameter: qsResultWithoutParameter.channelid === undefined");

// Now set the channelid after the function is called
qsResultWithoutParameter.channelid = "the-url-you-want";
console.log("Setting the channelid after the function is called: qsResultWithoutParameter.channelid === \"" + qsResultWithoutParameter.channelid + "\"");
```

Comment: Brother, your code is working very well I only need to be able to set the value of the url (channelid =) inside the `this.channelid` there in place of the" test "

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can choose how you set `this.channelid`. Either inside the function itself using a parameter or after the function is called

Comment: Robbie Vercammen I used your first code and another to get the parameters of the url and it worked, thank you my brother !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes: `"qs.channelid"` is a static string, while `qs` is object and `qs.channelid` is its dynamic property, which value you want to read. So it will be:

```
function urlId(qs) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("data-channel-external-id", qs.channelid); 
}
urlId(qs);
```